# Where should I call MediaPlayer.start();

Tags: java, android

I am new to android development :)

I am trying to run audio in the background using MediaPlayer, I have a foreground service set up my question is where should I call the `mediaPlayer.start()` do I just call it inside the service class, or do I call it in the activity class and start the service at the same time or do I have to run a thread and call the `mediaPlayer.start()` inside it while calling the thread inside a service class or activity class?

I tried calling it inside a service class and inside the activity class while calling `startService()` everything worked fine and the audio did not stop after a while.

Comment: You need a context to start a MediaPlayer, so you could create an instance of your encapsulating class which starts a MediaPlayer using the context from onCreate(). I dont quite know where you got your Context instance from if you started it outside of an activity. You can stop your MediaPlayer in the onStop()-Method in your activity as it might keep playing otherwise (as long as the app is not closed). You won't need a new thread - android creates one for you. You can call MediaPlayer.setLooping(true); to have it looping and call play in an OnLoadCompleteListener if loading problems occur.

Comment: I got the context from a class that extends a service class that run's a foreground service so that the app does not get killed after playing the audio for a while in the background. The classes that extend a service class act as a context by themselves you just have to call this or getApplicationContext().

Answer (score 0):

You should start media player inside activity class:

```
// media player uses context to create instance
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(this);
MediaMetadata mediaMetaData = new MediaMetadata.Builder()
                .putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, "Your video title").build();

UriMediaItem item = new UriMediaItem.Builder(Uri.parse(url))
                .setMetadata(mediaMetaData) // optional
                .build();

sourceVideoPreview.setPlayer(mediaPlayer);
mediaPlayer.setMediaItem(item);
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.play();
```

Note: This code works and you can use it outside activity too, but you need to pass context outside activity to create media player instance.